# how to disconnect users to MySQL but still allow admin login

Tags: mysql, block

Silly questions from a beginner: I wonder what is the best approach to : disconnect all users to MysQL but still allow console interactive connection, or admin connected from a MySQL Workbench?

I found various posts about killing connections, but if you just kill them, the users/applications may attempt to connect again.

I suppose I could kill the connections and remove the users that I want to block from mysql.user table, then after I've done the changes, put them back? I'd think there must be a better approach..
many thanks

--edit--

Thanks for the replies! I tried the 1st suggestion, ie. set max_user_connections = 1.
When I executed that set cmd, I have 2 connections: i) console login as root, from where I ran this cmd; ii) MySQL Workbench as a user running on a desktop PC.

The problem is that after the execution, I could still run select queries from the MySql workbench as the user. It is AFTER I closed MySQL workbench on the PC, then restarted, a new connection was refused.

In short, running this cmd does not disconnect existing connections, but will only stop new connections.

Does it mean I must kill all user connections first, then set max_user_connections=1?

Answer (score 1):

From your shell type the following:

From mysql console

`set global max_user_connections=1;`

That's it!

Comment: ...though if one of the users logged on, the admin wouldn't be able to get in.

Comment: There are other possibilities then. Either allow connections only from localhost where users from outside cannot make a connection, or you set up iptables to limit connections up to 1. See --connlimit-above 1 -j REJECT|DROP.

Third option is to allow only a specific IP range to connect to mysql server. A lot of other options are possible.

Comment: @Driftpeasant http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/too-many-connections.html "mysqld actually permits max_connections+1 clients to connect. The extra connection is reserved for use by accounts that have the SUPER privilege."